# Whether to use exceptions in C++ for Socket library?

Tags: c++, sockets, exception

I plan to build a portable Socket library with C++ programming language. As we known, errors occurs frequently in network programming. Some of them are recoverable, while others are not. I plan to use exceptions in C++ to trace the exception, do some logging operations and inform end-users. However using exceptions is extremely difficult, and using classic techniques like error codes will lead the code hard to read (lots of `if` statements). So what's your preference?

By the way, is there any light-weighted socket library (education-purposed is welcomed, and something like Ace is really hard to understand)?

Comment: Library code targeting multiple platforms is best written without C++ exceptions. Exception support is vastly different across platforms. If a client wishes to implement an exception model on top of the library core, they can easily write a wrapper.

Comment: I expect this to get closed for being primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

The downside of using return codes is that people forget error handling. This cannot happen with exceptions. However, if you write a return code class that asserts in its destructor unless the return value was read or explicitly ignored you can get the portability and performance of return values without the disadvantage of poor error handling. You still have to manually forward error codes if the caller needs to handle an exception.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question all boils down to where and how you expect to deal with error conditions.

Exception handling really comes into its own in parsers when one needs needs to return from some deeply nested code before it makes sense to handle the error. Checking error codes will be a useless burden.

IO might be slightly different in that it make sense to deal with the error at least to some extent close to the point of failure. If the error is allowed to propagate upwards one will lose context and make error handling ineffective.

Whatever you decide to do always log the point of failure so that you can debug it properly later. Exceptions tend to hide the point of failure and make debugging really difficult.

Answer (score 0):

> I plan to build a portable Socket library with C++ programming language.

Nice Idea. But have a look around for an existing one.

> As we known, errors occurs frequently in network programming.

Yes.

> Some of them are recoverable, while others are not.

True.

> So what's your preference?

A combination of both.

Internally within my socket library I use error codes between functions. Check the result and take appropriate actions. If the action is recoverable (i.e. simply re-try the read) then no exceptions are uses. If the issue is not recoverable then I will throw an exception as I can't fix it in the socket library the resolution needs more context so throw an exception and allow the using code impose the correct resolution based on the usage.

> By the way, is there any light-weighted socket library (education-purposed is welcomed, and something like Ace is really hard to understand)?

No documentation but very simple to use:

https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSocket

If you want to see a socket wrapped to look like a C++ stream:

https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsStream